# Creating a canvas and setting it's width fails on the second attempt

Tags: javascript, canvas, selector

I have created two canvas elements to draw on. They are both standard  elements with different ids.

I select the first with javascript, get the context and assign a width of 100vw to both. Works as intended.

I repeat the exact same code to select the second canvas, I get a "undefined" object from identical canvas + context selector:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvasbg"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
<script>
// select fore and background canvases
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
var canvasbg = document.getElementById('canvasbg'); // object found

// get canvas 2D context and set them correct size
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
var ctxbg = canvasbg.getContext('2d'); // object found

resize();

function resize() {
  var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var winHeight = window.innerHeight;

  ctx.canvas.width = winWidth; // works perfectly
  ctx.canvas.height = winHeight; // works perfectly

  ctxbg.canvasbg.width = winWidth; // console error: cannot set widht of undefined....???
  ctxbg.canvasbg.height = winHeight;
}
</script>
```

No idea what to do about this. This should be so basic.

Where can the issue be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `canvas` in `ctx.canvas` is the [CanvasRenderingContext2d.canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/canvas) property, not your `var canvas` variable.

So to access the one from the `ctxbg` context, you also need to access it by `.canvas`:

```
  ctxbg.canvas.width = winWidth;
  ctxbg.canvas.height = winHeight;
```